# Proving associativity

Tags: group-theory

consider $G = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with binary operation $\star$ s.t. $a \star b = |b-a|$

my attempt;

$(a\star b)\star c = |c - a\star b| = |c - |b-a||$
$a\star (b\star c) = |(b \star c) - a| = ||c-b| -a|$ so since $ (a \star b) \star c \not = a \star (b \star c)$ not associative, but how can I further justify that they are not equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show they aren't *always* equal, it is enough to pick a triple where they aren't. To show they are always equal, you'd have to check all possible cases (i.e., $a > b$, $a = b$, $a < b$). You can probably cut all that down quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The most convincing way to prove that a general statement (a *for all* statement) is untrue is by finding a counter-example.  In this case, the statement is that
$$(a \star b) \star c = a \star (b \star c)$$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, or equivalently that $$|c-|b-a||=||c-b|-a|$$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

So, we can pick three numbers, say $a=1,b=2,c=3$, and see if they form a counter-example.  We check $$(a \star b) \star c = |3-|2-1||=|3-1|=2$$ and $$a \star (b \star c) = ||3-2|-1|=|1-1|=0.$$

The choice to use $1,2,3$ was just a guess (and it turned out to give a counter-example in this case).